# need a math about (byte) 190 = -66

Tags: type-conversion

Arduino decode problem :

```
inString = "BE";
val = unhex（inString）; // the result of val = 190
(byte) val;// val 190 convert to byte return -66
```

How val converted from int to byte? any math?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're working with ***signed byte*** (which is typical for, say, *Java*):

```
  0xBE == 190
```

But `190 > 127` that's why it's *negative* (providing that byte is *signed* and so should be in range `[-128..127]`). To find out the value of `190` representation you should find ***N*** such that

```
 190 + N * 256 lies in [-128..127] range
```

in your case `N == -1`, and the answer is

```
  190 - 256 == -66
```